# Timeout waiting for connection from pool - despite single SolrServer

Tags: solr, httpclient, spring-data, solrj, spring-data-solr

We are having problems with our solrServer client's connection pool running out of connections in no time, even when using a pool of several hundred (we've tried 1024, just for good measure).

From what I've read, the following exception can be caused by not using a singleton HttpSolrServer object. However, see our XML config below, as well:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:232)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:199)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:455)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:448)
```

XML Config:

```
<solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://solr.url.domain/"/>
<solr:repositories base-package="de.ourpackage.data.solr" multicore-support="true"/>
```

At this point, we are at a loss. We are running a web application on a tomcat7. Whenever a user requests a new website, we send one or more request to the Solr Server, requesting whatever we need, which are usually single entries or page of 20 (using Spring Data).

As for the rest of our implementation, we are using an abstract SolrOperationsrepository class, which is extended by each of our repositories (one repository for each core).

The following is how we set our solrServer. I suspect we are doing something fundamentally wrong here, which is why our connections are overflowing. **According to the logs, they are always being returned into the pool, btw.**

```
private SolrOperations solrOperations;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        return (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public final SolrOperations getSolrOperations() {
        /*HttpSolrServer solrServer = (HttpSolrServer)solrOperations.getSolrServer();
        solrServer.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);*/
        logger.info("solrOperations: " + solrOperations);
        return solrOperations;
    }

    @Autowired
    public final void setSolrServer(SolrServer solrServer) {
        try {
            String core = SolrServerUtils.resolveSolrCoreName(getEntityClass());
            SolrTemplate template = templateHolder.get(core);
            /*solrServer.setConnectionTimeout(500);
            solrServer.setMaxTotalConnections(2048);
            solrServer.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(2048);
            solrServer.getHttpClient().getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);*/

            if ( template == null ) {
                template = new SolrTemplate(new MulticoreSolrServerFactory(solrServer));
                template.setSolrCore(core);
                template.afterPropertiesSet();

                logger.debug("Creating new SolrTemplate for core '" + core + "'");
                templateHolder.put(core, template);
            }
            logger.debug("setting SolrServer " + template);

            this.solrOperations = template;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("cannot set solrServer...", e);
        }
    }
```

The code that is commented out has been mostly used for testing purposes. I also read somewhere else that you cannot manipulate the solrServer object on-the-fly. Which begs the question, how do I set a timeout/poolsize in the XML config?

The implementation of a repository looks like this:

```
@Repository(value="stellenanzeigenSolrRepository")
public class StellenanzeigenSolrRepositoryImpl extends SolrOperationsRepository<Stellenanzeige> implements StellenanzeigenSolrRepositoryCustom {
...
    public Query createQuery(Criteria criteria, Sort sort, Pageable pageable) {
        Query resultQuery = new SimpleQuery(criteria);
        if ( pageable != null ) resultQuery.setPageRequest(pageable);
        if ( sort != null ) resultQuery.addSort(sort);
        return resultQuery;
    }

    public Page<Stellenanzeige> findBySearchtext(String searchtext, Pageable pageable) {
        Criteria searchtextCriteria = createSearchtextCriteria(searchtext);
        Query query = createQuery(searchtextCriteria, null, pageable);
        return getSolrOperations().queryForPage(query, getEntityClass());
    }
...
}
```

Can any of you point to mistakes that we've made, that could possibly lead to this issue? Like I said, we are at a loss. Thanks in advance, and I will, of course update the question as we make progress or you request more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MulticoreServerFactory always returns an object of HttpClient, that only ever allows 2 concurrent connections to the same host, thus causing the above problem.

This seems to be a bug with spring-data-solr that can be worked around by creating a custom factory and overriding a few methods.

Edit: The clone method in MultiCoreSolrServerFactory is broken. This hasn't been corrected yet. As some of my colleagues have run into this issue recently, I will post a workaround here - create your own class and override one method.

```
public class CustomMulticoreSolrServerFactory extends MulticoreSolrServerFactory {

    public CustomMulticoreSolrServerFactory(final SolrServer solrServer) {
        super(solrServer);
    }

    @Override
    protected SolrServer createServerForCore(final SolrServer reference, final String core) {
        // There is a bug in the original SolrServerUtils.cloneHttpSolrServer()
        // method
        // that doesn't clone the ConnectionManager and always returns the
        // default
        // PoolingClientConnectionManager with a maximum of 2 connections per
        // host

        if (StringUtils.hasText(core) && reference instanceof HttpSolrServer) {
            HttpClient client = ((HttpSolrServer) reference).getHttpClient();
            String baseURL = ((HttpSolrServer) reference).getBaseURL();
            baseURL = SolrServerUtils.appendCoreToBaseUrl(baseURL, core);
            return new HttpSolrServer(baseURL, client);
        }

        return reference;
    }

}
```